# Proper way to create new SQL table in a MediaWiki Extension

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am creating a mediawiki extension that needs is own SQL table. What's the proper way to create it in the extension, and do I need to create separate SQL code for each database I want to support, the way the [OATHAuth extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OATHAuth) does? That doesn't seem like the right approach.

(OATHAuth hooks `onLoadExtensionSchemaUpdates`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a schema change for an extension, the [*LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates* hook page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates) is the right place to look.

The *LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates* hook is

> fired when MediaWiki is updated (php maintenance/update.php) to allow extensions to update the
>   database

If you take a look at the *ArticleFeedbackv5.sql* [file](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EAFF/browse/REL1_29/sql/ArticleFeedbackv5.sql), that's basically what the [sql file](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SQL_patch_file) should look like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /*_*/aft_feedback (
      -- id is no auto-increment, but a in PHP generated unique value
      aft_id binary(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      aft_page integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    ...
    ) /*$wgDBTableOptions*/;

    -- sort indexes (central feedback page; lots of data - more details indexes for most popular actions)
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/relevance ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_relevance_score, aft_id, aft_has_comment, aft_oversight, aft_archive, aft_hide);
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/age ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_timestamp, aft_id, aft_has_comment, aft_oversight, aft_archive, aft_hide);
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/helpful ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_net_helpful, aft_id, aft_has_comment, aft_oversight, aft_archive, aft_hide);

    -- page-specific
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/relevance_page ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_page, aft_relevance_score);
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/age_page ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_page, aft_timestamp);
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/helpful_page ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_page, aft_net_helpful);

    -- index for archive-job
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/archive_queue ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_archive, aft_archive_date);

    -- index for mycontribs data
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/contribs ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_user, aft_timestamp);
    CREATE INDEX /*i*/contribs_anon ON /*_*/aft_feedback (aft_user, aft_user_text, aft_timestamp);
```

And then you reference this file in the [hook](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EAFF/browse/REL1_29/ArticleFeedbackv5.hooks.php$67) in your hook file

```
public static function loadExtensionSchemaUpdates( $updater = null ) {
            // that's for adding a table
            $updater->addExtensionTable(
                'aft_feedback',
                dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/sql/ArticleFeedbackv5.sql' //that's the previous sql file
            );
            ...
}
```

Don't forget to add the hook in the hook section in your `extension.json` file. The table will be created when you run the `update.php` file.

As for your question regarding creating a file for each database engine, we can't use the same file for each of them as there might be some differences in the queries. See what [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683843/11758901) said.

If you haven't yet, take a look at the [hook file](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-OATHAuth/blob/master/src/Hook/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates/UpdateTables.php).

```
protected function execute() {
        switch ( $this->updater->getDB()->getType() ) {
            case 'mysql':
            case 'sqlite':
                $this->updater->addExtensionTable( 'oathauth_users', "{$this->base}/sql/mysql/tables.sql" );
                $this->updater->addExtensionUpdate( [ [ $this, 'schemaUpdateOldUsersFromInstaller' ] ] );
                $this->updater->dropExtensionField(
                    'oathauth_users',
                    'secret_reset',
                    "{$this->base}/sql/mysql/patch-remove_reset.sql"
                );
                $this->updater->addExtensionField(
                    'oathauth_users',
                    'module',
                    "{$this->base}/sql/mysql/patch-add_generic_fields.sql"
                );
                $this->updater->addExtensionUpdate(
                    [ [ __CLASS__, 'schemaUpdateSubstituteForGenericFields' ] ]
                );
                $this->updater->dropExtensionField(
                    'oathauth_users',
                    'secret',
                    "{$this->base}/sql/mysql/patch-remove_module_specific_fields.sql"
                );
                /*$this->updaterAddExtensionUpdate(
                    [ [ __CLASS__, 'schemaUpdateTOTPToMultipleKeys' ] ]
                );*/
                break;
            case 'oracle':
                $this->updater->addExtensionTable( 'oathauth_users', "{$this->base}/sql/oracle/tables.sql" );
                break;
            case 'postgres':
                $this->updater->addExtensionTable( 'oathauth_users', "{$this->base}/sql/postgres/tables.sql" );
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need a patch file for each supported DB engine. In theory it could be the same patch file, in practice there are usually subtle syntax differences that necessitate separate files. There are some [planned changes](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T191231) to replace the current schema updater system with abstract schema changes so that extension developers do not have to deal with DB engine differences, but it will take a while for that to happen.

In practice, most extensions deal with this by only supporting MySQL and maybe Postgres.